# Keeping user logged in after changing password (Django) custom user model

Tags: python, django

I have a customized Django model. My problem is whenever I update any of the user profile information, it logged out. I know that Django logged out the user after changing their password and I have to use update_session_auth_hash() function. However, in my case it didn't work and I don't want to use Django changePasswordForm because I want the user to be able to change all his information in one form. Any help will be appreciated.

This is my custom user model:

```
class MyUser(AbstractBaseUser):
   firstName = models.CharField(max_length=100, validators =[firstnameCheck] )
   lastName = models.CharField(max_length=100, validators =[lastnameCheck] )
   #nationalID = models.IntegerField(unique=True)
   nationalID = models.CharField(max_length=10, validators=[RegexValidator(r'^[0-9]{10}$')], unique=True)
   GENDER_CHOICES = [('male', 'Male'), ('female', 'Female')]
   gender = models.CharField(choices=GENDER_CHOICES, max_length=10)
   dateofbirth = models.DateField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False)
   email = models.EmailField(max_length=100, unique=True)
   password = models.CharField(max_length=100)
   password_confirm = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='')
   is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
   is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
   is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
   is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)

   USERNAME_FIELD = 'email' #enable authentication by using email instead of default 'username'
   REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['firstName', 'lastName', 'nationalID','gender','dateofbirth','password','password_confirm']

   objects = MyUserManager() 

   def __str__(self):
       return self.email

   def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
       return True

   def has_module_perms(self,app_label):
       return True
```

This is my view

```
def update_admin(request,id):
context = {}
if request.method == "POST":
    pi = MyUser.objects.get(pk=id)
    fm = UserRegisterationForm(request.POST,instance=pi)
    if fm.is_valid():
        request.user.set_password(fm.cleaned_data['password1'])
        fm.save()
        update_session_auth_hash(request, request.user)
        messages.add_message(request, messages.INFO, 'The profile updated successfully.')
    context['form'] = fm

else:
    pi = MyUser.objects.get(pk=id)
    fm = UserRegisterationForm(instance=pi)
    context['form'] = fm


return render(request,'project/update_admin.html', context)
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the change of the password will make the session invalid.

See [doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/auth/default/#session-invalidation-on-password-change)

You could also heredity the django change password form for your own form.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this.

Template:

```
<form method="POST" class="contact-form" action="{% url 'change-password' %}"> ##make sure the action links to the `changepassword` view
{% csrf_token %}
    <input type="password" name="password" required id="password" pattern="^[a-zA-Z0-9]{6,}$">
</div>
<button type="submit">Submit</button>

</form>
```

Views.py:

```
def changepassword(request):

   user = request.user

   if 'password' in request.POST:
       user.set_password(request.POST['password'])
       

return render(request, 'project/changepassword.html')
```

This will keep your user logged in after the password change, but you will need to add validation handling & error handling to this to make it a viable solution.